# How can a TCP connection be passed through a routing server in AWS to its originator to avoid timeouts?

Tags: amazon-ec2, smtp, bastion

I'm a front end developer that has found myself needing to solve a backend issue with a site I'm working on. I did not set it up and am trying to understand how its currently structured. Within AWS there are 2 EC2 instances in the same VPC. One with the site content lets call it "Server A" and another instance with the sites public ip "server B". I assume server B is acting as some sort of router.

I need to setup sending emails from server A but it has no public IP. I setup SES to send mail through but connections timeout for smtp over port 587. I tested the connection via telnet and it worked for Server B but not Server A. They both have the same settings for selinux, firewalld and iptables.

Both servers are running Centos. both servers have the same aws security privileges (port 587 out and ports 1024-65535 in)

The best I can tell is that connection to server A are passed through Server B. How would I get a TCP connection to pass through server B to server A. In many ways this is beyond my understanding to even be able to describe/research well so any help to push me in the right direction is much appreciated!